# AWS Lambda - Unable to make a request using RestSharp

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, lambda, .net-core, restsharp

I am getting an error when trying to make a simple request using RestSharp.  My environment is AWS Lambda --> .NET Core 2.0 --> Restsharp 106.2.1.  Any ideas?

code:

```
string sUrl = "http://httpbin.org";
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri(sUrl);
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/get";
request.Method = Method.GET;
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

error:

```
{
  "errorType": "JsonSerializationException",
  "errorMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'Request.OnBeforeDeserialization.Method.Module.Assembly'.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[T](T response, Stream responseStream)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the JSON recieved ?

Comment: `{
    "args": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "Postman-Token": "6a08cca7-6208-4eb2-ab48-671d9dac3bcd",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/6.2.5"
    },
    "origin": "74.203.213.6",
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}`

Comment: If you run this exact same code in visual studio using .NET 4.5 it will resolve  correctly.  I am trying to run the same code in a AWS lambda using .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: The error is caused by what your Lambda function is returning back to API Gateway. Are you returning back an APIGatewayResponse or your own custom type?

Comment: I agree with @NormJohanson. RestSharp is not using Newtonsoft.Json. The error comes outside of the RestSharp request execution scope. You cannot find any RestSharp methods in the stacktrace and this should give you the clue.